# XUbuntu 16.04 WiFi problems

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, xubuntu, intel-wireless

I've got XUbuntu 16.04 and my HP dv6t quad edition laptop won't connect to some wifi access points.

```
$ uname -a
Linux maya 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linu
```

Hopefully this is the right log file to look at:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/kern.log
Oct  7 09:06:31 maya NetworkManager[1604]: <info>  [1475856391.9237] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'Pismo Lighthouse Suites' (a54852a2-0ef8-4f14-bb91-e98eda7bce14)
Oct  7 09:06:31 maya NetworkManager[1604]: <info>  [1475856391.9240] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="a54852a2-0ef8-4f14-bb91-e98eda7bce14" name="Pismo Lighthouse Suites" pid=3235 uid=1000 result="success"
Oct  7 09:06:31 maya NetworkManager[1604]: <info>  [1475856391.9242] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Oct  7 09:06:31 maya NetworkManager[1604]: <info>  [1475856391.9245] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct  7 09:06:31 maya NetworkManager[1604]: <info>  [1475856391.9262] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Oct  7 09:06:31 maya NetworkManager[1604]: <info>  [1475856391.9271] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Pismo Lighthouse Suites' has security, but secrets are required.
Oct  7 09:06:31 maya NetworkManager[1604]: <info>  [1475856391.9275] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Oct  7 09:06:56 maya NetworkManager[1604]: <warn>  [1475856416.9562] device (wlo1): No agents were available for this request.
Oct  7 09:06:56 maya NetworkManager[1604]: <info>  [1475856416.9563] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [60 120 7]
Oct  7 09:06:56 maya NetworkManager[1604]: <info>  [1475856416.9567] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct  7 09:06:56 maya NetworkManager[1604]: <warn>  [1475856416.9572] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'Pismo Lighthouse Suites'
Oct  7 09:06:56 maya NetworkManager[1604]: <info>  [1475856416.9579] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Oct  7 09:06:56 maya kernel: [  106.646942] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
```

Output of the [wireless-info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) script:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23289569

Comment: Have you tried disabling N-wireless with `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` ?

Comment: Just tried that, and rebooted, but no apparent improvement

Comment: Ok.  If you want to undo that command, edit `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and take that 11n_disable line out.  I just thought I'd give it a shot because that fixed issues with my HP DV7.  I also disabled ipv6 so try it out just for the heck of it.